# Regex: Matching two words with a gap in-between

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match two specific words with 30 (or less) characters in between.
For example:

```
"mike" + "any number of characters but less than 31" + "jagger"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
"mike.{,30}?jagger"
```

This will match any string containing `"mike"` followed by 0 to 30 arbitrary characters (as few as required in order to match) followed by `"jagger"`.

Comment: You can shorten it one character by using `{,30}` ;)

Comment: Now, something that might actually matter - I think it should be non-greedy, otherwise `mikejaggerjagger` won't catch the first occurrence. So `{,30}?`.

Comment: @minitech: Hmm, I guess it depends on what the OP really wants. Non-greedy is probably more likely, though -- I'll change my answer. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys..one more question please..is there a way to match both "mike""less than 30 chars""jagger" and 
"jagger""less than 30 chars""mike"

Comment: @user1056676: Yep, just reverse the place of each word. If you want to match both with a single regex, you can use: `"(?:mike.{,30}?jagger)|(?:jagger.{,30}?mike)"`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\bmike\b.{0,30}\bjagger\b")) {
    // Successful match
}
```

You are saying that you want to match **specific** words. If you don't use word anchors then you can match things like : `blamikelol`